# Logic app check null values on array then replace it with string

Tags: arrays, loops, null, element, azure-logic-apps

So I am trying to check for array null values inside a loop but I don't really know the right format for that

Array example:

```
[
  'value 1',
  'value 2',
  '',
  'value 4',
]
```

this is the expression that I tried to write:

```
if(empty(outputs('splitTD')[variables('FirstRecord')]), replace(outputs('splitTD')[variables('FirstRecord')], '', 'Not specified' ), outputs('splitTD')[variables('FirstRecord')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, I have initialized array with your given input and then again initialized another empty array and then, I have used condition `if(empty(item()),'No Element',item())` in for each loop and got results and followed below process:

[image]

**The in compose variable as below:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

You need to on your concurrency as below for getting in Right Order:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I tried your solution but the result i got is not on the same order I want it is there a solution for that?

Comment: @user20829088, I have edited my answer at end according to your requirement and let me know if this works for you and i guess it should work

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use an inline expression with an entire array.  I tried to convert the array to a string and use a `replace` expression but it just didn't want to be converted back to an array.

You need to loop over it and do the processing that way.  Also, if you want to make sure the array stays in its original order, you need to turn concurrency to 1, otherwise, it will run in parallel and invoke race condition style outcomes to the updated array.

The component within the loop is the IF statement, it will determine what to do with each item.

```
if(or(equals(item(),null), equals(item(), '')), 'Not specified', item())
```

Load this into your tenant to see a working version.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_Each_Array_Item": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_To_Updated_Array": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Updated Array",
                            "value": "@if(or(equals(item(),null), equals(item(), '')), 'Not specified', item())"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Updated_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Array",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "value 1",
                                "value 2",
                                "",
                                "value 4"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Updated_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Updated Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

This is the end result (this compose statement doesn't exist in the JSON above but you don't need) ...

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I tried your if statement code my project but it does not work as I expect. I see that you got your result on the same order I don't why for my it is not the same. So for my project I use 2 loop and 2 arrays. First one will loop to append data in the first array. Then second one will loop and check null then append to the other array. It did check for data and replace but result is not on the same order.

Comment: Yeah, the concurrency.